# How to bridge github ci network and docker container network

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I currently have a github e2e test worflow that needs a container to run the CI on:

```
container:
      image: myImage
      credentials:
        username: ${{ github.repository_owner }}
        password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

It is spawned in github's network, for example:

```
github_network_73cc75f128a140e8b0ccfd894f1352fa
```

Unfortunately, I have a step further down the e2e test that requires spinning up a docker image for an auth service that is on docker's network. The command is something like:

```
. e2e/env.sh && scripts/dockert docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up auth
```

And it's network is, for example:

```
myServicee2e_default
```

Because they are 2 different networks, the service in github's CI is unable to talk to the auth service in the docker network but is dependent on it to pass.

How can I make sure they are spawned in the same network or make them communicate between each other?

Comment: Have you defined a docker network?

Comment: Nope, not yet. Do you mean I should define one in my worlflow.yml and docker-compose file?

Comment: Yes. If you don't create a docker network, every docker use it's own one. So, add to your docker-compose.yml file a `networks:` for both dockers called with the same name.
https://docs.docker.com/network/

Comment: @AlejandroGalera have you found how to do this? I see nothing network related in https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer